# Validation in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate user input in a form instantly using jquery. I have written this segment, but actually it doesn't do what I want. I suppose that it should show a message if the user doesn't agree. Moreover, it was working properly for a period, but then it doesn't work. thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>
<script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1").validate({
messages: {
checkbox1: {required: 'you must agree'}
        }
}
);
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="apDiv1">
<h1 style="text-align:center">STEP ONE</h1>
</div>

<form  id="form1" action="action.php"  method="post">

 Enter Your Number
    <label>
      <input name="textfield1" type="text" id="textfield1" />
    </label>

 <p/>
 I agree
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" validate="required:true"/>

 <p/>   
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"  />


</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the difference between your code and the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8pd8/)? It seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Whitaker. I have tried it on jsFiddle, and it actually works correctly. But when I test it on my browser offline (e.g localhost in Firefox and chrome), it doesn't work. Also, I thought that the version of jquery may has effect on it, but this is not true because I've tested more than one version, and all of them give me correct result on jsFidle and no result on my localhost.

Comment: @creativeCreative : check whether your js files are in correct path?

Comment: They are in the correct path, I'm sure. Thanks mahesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's been solved.Here is what I did exactly:

I moved the lib folder to the upper directory so the associated tags would look like this

```
<script src="../lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also I put the file jquery.validate.js one level up, and the script will be:

```
<script src="../jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Actually, I don't know what is the problem with directories, but It works in this manner.
Thanks you for your answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark...

Don't use the name 'submit' as the name attribute of your submit button...

Thats got me a few occasions with the occasional plugin.

Dom

Comment: Thanks, but in fact, that didn't help me in this issue.